# How to replace war file on live server without site goes down

Tags: java, tomcat6

I am not able to find solution change new war file with existing war file on server, i have simple solution just remove existing war file from server and upload new war file on server but *site goes down till the time new war file uploading*.
Please suggest me what i can, i don't want site goes down.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting the old war, you can just copy the new war over it (hot deploy). That will at least shorten the downtime since you're not waiting for the war to upload.

If you want it to be even shorter, you'll need 2 servers with a load balancer to make sure that you can direct the traffic to one server while the other one is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Zero-Downtime Deployment

Since Tomcat 7 it is possible to deploy an app more then once, just by naming the war.

webapps/foo##001.war => will be deployed as host/foo
webapps/foo##002.war => will also be deployed as host/foo

old sessions will be served by 001, new sessions will start with 002.

There is a good article here: http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1288